# Init plugin again after ajax call finish

Tags: plugins, ajax, init, infinite-scroll

We have [this website](http://touringisrael.com/) that the navigation between pages work with ajax.

in the [blog page](http://touringisrael.com/blog) we use [this great plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll-and-load-more-ajax-pagination/) to make the ajax load-more posts.

all works great but the problem is that when you come from another page to the blog page the plugin don't work and you get the "Older Entries" string in the left bottom corner,

if i refresh the page the plugin work great.

so im looking for way to init the plugin not only when page load but when ajax call finish too(every page navigation make ajax call)

thanks!